# WSO2 APIM PUBLISHER - issue with importing swagger definition

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

When trying to import the swagger definition into WSO2 APIM publisher - the wso2 apim publisher failing with the following error -

> ERROR - RhinoEngine org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1
>   column 11 (http#17)
>
> ERROR - WebAppManager org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1
>   column 11 (http#17)
>
> org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1
>   column 11 (http#17)

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Sounds like it's a malformed Swagger specification. Can you add it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the swagger definition for syntax errors .seems there is a json syntax error. use json validator like [jsLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your APIM version is 1.8.

Can you please tryout below solution to fix the issue.

Move 'XMLHttpRequest' instance creation inside for loop in file, \repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\site\blocks\item-design\ajax\import.jag

```
Ex:
for(var i = 0; i < swaggerJson.apis.length; i++){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url + swaggerJson.apis[i].path);
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved in the new WSO2 APIM 3.0 version.
Try this out : 
https://wso2.com/api-management/